# Image doesn't fill top of div. Background color creates unwanted line at top of image

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a variable image inside. The max image height is set to 100% so regular images should fill the entire div. However on some screens I can see the background (red in the example) which spills over the image. Is there a way to fix this?

Here is a screenshot of the red line which shows up at random screensizes:
[image]

```css
.image.cell {
    background-color: red;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

img {
    max-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image cell large-offset-1 large-10">
  <img srcset="" src="https://i.imgur.com/eRM6hHb.jpeg" alt="Aliquam eu est lectus">
</div>
```

Comment: Could you check that you have enough code in your snippet to demonstrate the problem? As it stands the image has red to the left and right. I can see you are giving the cell a fixed aspect ratio.

Comment: Can you alter the CSS to make it padding-top not bottom just to check that the red line goes to the bottom not the top? [I can't manage to reproduce the problem myself otherwise I'd try it]. I think you are seeing a problem of part pixels being 'left behind' on the screen as several screen pixels are used for one CSS pixel on many modern screens.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does the `run code snippet` not work for you? If you make the `result` box smaller by downsizing the screen you should see the line appear at lower screensizes.

Changed to padding-top but still line shows at top. Probably because of the transform translate.

Comment: The line is the clearest on firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `<img>` tag, try using `background-image`. It generally gives you way more control over the way your images are displayed. I've adjusted your css for you!

```
.image.cell {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/eRM6hHb.jpeg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repear: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: auto;
}
```

You can set the `height` to whatever you want. The image's `width` will change automatically.

Comment: the width doesnt seem to auto-resize to show the entire picture it seems.

Comment: My bad if I explained it incorrectly. You can adjust the ``height`` to show the entire picture, while ``width: auto`` preserves its aspect ratio so that it doesn't get streched when you increase the height.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a changes in your css code, you can check it.
We can provide all the style attributes for .image.cell class.

```css
.image.cell {
    background-color: red;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="image cell large-offset-1 large-10">
      <img srcset="" src="https://i.imgur.com/eRM6hHb.jpeg" alt="Aliquam eu est lectus">
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! But the image doesn't resize this way. Whenever the screen is downsized bits are just cut-off instead of the image keeping its ratio.